# How to access values in XmlElementAttributte in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I am calling a web service operation in .NET which returns xml data with the following class object:

```
    public partial class data : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("currentRow", typeof(dataCurrentRow), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("deleteRow", typeof(dataDeleteRow), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("insertRow", typeof(dataInsertRow), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("modifyRow", typeof(dataModifyRow), Order=0)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }



    public partial class dataCurrentRow : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private object[] columnValueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("columnValue", Order=0)]
    public object[] columnValue {
        get {
            return this.columnValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.columnValueField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("columnValue");
        }
    }
```

Xml returned from the web service call:

```
      <QAS_GETQUERYRESULTS_RESP_MSG xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/QAS_GETQUERYRESULTS_RESP_MSG.VERSION_1">
     <webRowSet xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdbc">
        <properties>
    ...
    ...
        </properties>
        <metadata>
    ...
    ...
        </metadata>
        <data>
           <currentRow>
              <columnValue>abc</columnValue>
              <columnValue>123</columnValue>
              <columnValue>xyz</columnValue>
           </currentRow>
           <currentRow>
              <columnValue>def</columnValue>
              <columnValue>456</columnValue>
              <columnValue>opq</columnValue>
           </currentRow>
        </data>
     </webRowSet>
  </QAS_GETQUERYRESULTS_RESP_MSG>
```

However, I am not sure how to access the xml values "columnValue" in .NET with the class object "data". Please help to show me how I can access the values. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to answer without all the code, however you should be able to iterate your 'Items' collection checking each one for its type. In the event that you find an item that is a 'typeof(dataCurrentRow)' you should then be able to cast the object as that type and access its property collection (which I hope is a collection of 'columnValue' objects. Do you have the dataCurrentRow object in another partial class if you can post this I could give you an example.

Edit  - you could use the column values (please note you will need to alter the object namespaces to be in-line with your own) -

```
        var myData = new data();
        //populate the data object via your webservice call.

        if (myData.Items != null && myData.Items.Length > 0)
        {
            var currentData = from c in myData.Items where c.GetType() == typeof(ConsoleApplication3.data.dataCurrentRow) select c as ConsoleApplication3.data.dataCurrentRow ;

            if (currentData != null && currentData.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in currentData)
                {
                    if(row != null && row.columnValue != null)
                        Console.WriteLine(row.columnValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I have added the partial class  dataCurrentRow to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Terry - added example to my original answer - HTH

Comment: I tested the example, it works fine! Thank you so much for your guidance :)